# Python not detecting existing modules

Tags: python, file, module, python-module

Trying to run a .py file on Kali Linux using:

```
`sudo python2 test.py`
```

I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    import selenium
ImportError: No module named selenium
```

The problem is that selenium is already installed, when pip is asked to install selenium this error message is shown:

```
sudo pip3 install selenium
```

I get this message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: selenium in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (4.0.0a1)
```

What should I do? I guess that it is related to pip2, but I cant install it. Please help me.
This the file's code:

```
import sys 
import datetime 
import selenium import requests 
import time as t from sys 
import stdout from selenium 
import webdriver from optparse 
import OptionParser
```

Comment: You're trying to run the file with Python 2, but you installed Selenium with pip3.

Comment: Just create a virtual environment, install the required packages and execute the program there.

Comment: pip3 is for python3, you run with python2

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple different versions of python on your system. The file you are running is with the `python2` interpreter. `pip3` is a package manager for `python3`.

If you want to see all your installed versions of python you can run `ls /usr/bin/python*` (just ignore `python-config` and `pythonw` directories). To install selenium on python2 you need to use `pip` instead of `pip3`. Alternatively, you can try running that file with `python3` since it doesn't look like there are any python2 print statements, xrange, etc. which might cause python3 to fail.

Comment: Which command should I use to install pip2?

Comment: Try running `pip -V`. If it gives you (python 2.x) at the end then use `pip install selenium`. If not then you'll have to do some more digging around

Comment: I got same error tying to get selenium from pip only.

Comment: is there anything stopping you from running the file using python3?

Comment: print '------------------------'
          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('------------------------')?

Comment: add parenthesis as it suggests